# What happens when submit button is clicked

Tags: html, get

What happens when submit button is clicked? Let I've a form which located on an `http://example.com/` URL with the two `input` elements like this:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="namefield1"/>
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="namefield2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

What actually get request will be sent to an `http`-server in my specific case?

Comment: download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and see what requests are sent.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see with the browser's debugging tools?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The form will be submitted to the server and the browser will redirect away to the current address of the browser and append as query string parameters the values of the input fields.

In terms of the HTTP protocol the following GET request HTTP request will be sent:

```
GET http://example.com/?namefield1=value1&namefield2=value2 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Since your `<form>` is missing an `action` attribute, the browser will simply redirect to the current url by appending the values as query string parameters. So if this form was loaded from `http://example.com/foo.php` after submitting it, the browser will redirect to `http://example.com/foo.php?namefield1=value1&namefield2=value2` where `value1` and `value2` will be the values enetered by the user in the corresponding input fields.

Also you might use your browser's built in debugging tools or [`Fiddler`](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the exact payload that gets sent to the server.

Comment: Why is `namefield1` sent twice?

Comment: It was a mistake. 2 parameters will be sent to the server.

Answer (score 4):

If you submit the form with a method of 'get' then it will perform a get request thus sending the data held within your input elements on the query string as a name value pair. So for example http://example.com/index.html?field1=joe&field2=bloggs

See example here if you scroll down to the Submit Button example at the bottom: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp