# What happens when we fill User Name and Password fields on a website and click login or submit button?

Tags: http, web, http-headers

I am little new to programming (especially to web designing). I have learned that the World Wide Web is based upon a protocol called HTTP. And also each and every item (I mean web pages, images, css & js files etc) are transferred according to the HTTP Requests. So my problem is this.

1. When we fill a web form (especially a login form like fb) and click ok, login or submit button, What Happens Next? Does it send another http request or does it use some special technique?
2. Is it safe or does anyone can hack our user names and passwords when that requests are traveling through internet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when submit button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814294/what-happens-when-submit-button-is-clicked)

Comment: Please read [ask], try searching before asking and share your research. [What happens when submit button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814294/what-happens-when-submit-button-is-clicked), [How secure is a HTTP POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008668/how-secure-is-a-http-post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on the person who made it. They can create an output which would show the values entered or it can be entered to a database for other usage. There's so many things can be done and that would actually depend on the need of the user.

Added for 2nd question:
There are a number of ways to encrypt these data to avoid being hacked. If you use a very basic technique in transferring the values that you submit then there would be a huge possibility that it can be hacked. But, not to worry as there are plenty of ways to be safe.