# Questions about Javascript IndexedDB while input information

Tags: javascript

My code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function set() {
                var db;
                var request;
                var store;

                var username = document.getElementById("username");
                var password = document.getElementById("password");
                var email = document.getElementById("email");
                var interest = document.getElementById("interest");
                var newuser = {
                        "username": username.value,
                        "password": password.value,
                        "email": email.value,
                        "interest": interest.value
                };
                var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB ||window.mozIndexedDB;
                if ('webkitIndexedDB' in window) {
                    window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
                    window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
                }
                request = indexedDB.open("userdb",1);
                request.onerror = function(event) {
                    alert("Error Code:" + event.target.errorCode);
                };
                request.onsuccess = function(event) {

                    if(username.value==""||password.value==""||email.value==""||interest.value==""){
                        alert("Incomplete information");
                    }else{
                        db=event.target.result;  
                        var transaction = db.transaction(["user"], "readwrite");  
                        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("user");  
                        objectStore.add(newuser);
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                };
                request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
                    db = event.target.result;  
                    store = db.createObjectStore("user", {keyPath: "username",autoIncrement: false});
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>
            Register
        </h3>
        <form>
            <p>
                Username
                <input type="text" id="username" />
            </p>
            <p>
                Password
                <input type="password" id="password" />
            </p>
            <p>
                Email
                <input type="email" id="email" />
            </p>
            <p>
                Interest
                <input type="text" id="interest" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="register" onclick="set();" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem is that every time I input the information and click the register button,request.success doesn't work.
Maybe I have an incorrect description.Thanks for your time to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens? What should happen?

Comment: Notice that you're not preventing the form from submitting, so it just will reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Bergi stated in the comment that you are not preventing default behavior of submit button which is reloading the page as you submit. See [What happens when submit button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814294/what-happens-when-submit-button-is-clicked).

What you should do is to pass the event argument when calling the function

```
<input type="submit" value="register" onclick="set(event);" />
```

And then prevent the events default behavior in your `set` function

```
function set(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var db;
    var request;
    ...
    ...
    //// your code
}
```

Will stop your page from reloading which is the default behavior of form submit button.