# Calling a file from ajax, Inside a javascript Funtion called display();

Tags: javascript, ajax

The below code is a html button inside a form tag.

```
 <form name="App" action="Mcd_S_Server.php" method="POST" onSubmit="">
<button id="btn-Check" onclick="display1();" >Check</button></form>
```

The below code is Javascript function  display1(); Inside this function i am calling a other file through ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display1()
{
     $.ajax({
     type    : "POST",
     url     : 'Mcd_Get_Data.php',
     cache   : false,
     dataType: 'json',
  });
}
</script>
```

Problem Statement:   When i click on that button it will hit the function, but it is not calling the URL mentioned in ajax i.e Mcd_Get_Data.php instead it is going to form action URL Mcd_S_Server.php. Why is this so ?Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include type attribute in your button element. Because by default it's of type `submit` ,So you need to override it of type `button`

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for your quick reply but ,i have added no changes.

Comment: And also call the success function of your Ajax

Comment: But in that Specified URL ,i have written. "Hello"exit. it doesn't go to that page.

Comment: It won't redirect you to any page.It will return you the response object as a parameter of your success callback fucntion

Comment: Response object will come,when i pass from that particular URL. Now it is not going to that page!

Comment: @AravindBhatK Glad it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your button with that,

```
<form name="App" action="Mcd_S_Server.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="button" id="btn-Check" onclick="display1();" value="Check"/>
</form>
```

See the related ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483257/url-mapping-using-jquery-in-spring-mvc/41484452#41484452)

Comment: Hi Ataur, thank you for your quick reply but ,i have added no changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function display1(event){
   event.preventDefault()
   ...
}
```

On click of the button the form is getting submitted you need to prevent that. Add event.preventDefault() to the display1 method as shown above.